# how to find and remove temporary data from server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, htmltextwriter

i am using a web bases rich text editor on my site to allow users to edit and format text.

When we add a picture, the text editor uploads the image file to the images directory on server and displays back through a URL from server.

But some people may delete a uploaded image and upload another few.

But that `deleted image` from `rich text editor`, is still on `server`.

Then pver time the server will fill with `unwanted files`. How can i can `remove` such like files?

Im working with `php`, on this task. give me some hints.

Comment: Can you parse the final contents of the rich text editor (once saved) and check for image references. You could then move those images to a "final" folder and delete anything left in the "upload" folder for that user. (You'd need to add a user identifier to the image though, so you didn't delete anything someone was still working on!)

Comment: Are the pictures uploaded globally? (can they be used on multiple pages?) And what do you mean by "deleted" from the editor? Do the users access some kind of library where they can delete the images, or do they just remove it from the editor?

Comment: @user2849406 . my problem is people may just remove it from the editor, but then those files are exist on server. i am thinking a way to remove the image from server just they remove it from html text editing area. as when we use blogger we can just upload and insert a image in to text editing area. and we can just remove the image by just one backspace keystroke.

Comment: @danielpsc idea is good. but when a person try to edit again, a saved page, after few days. then i have to move, all his image files again to tempory folder. then i have to face to a problem again.

Comment: Good point. The only other suggestion would be to implement a sort-of reference-counting/garbage collection system that would just run periodically on the server. This would maybe build an array of all of the uploaded image file names, then go through the saved content counting references to those images. You'd then be able to delete any that had a zero count at the end. But you'd need to build in a mechanism that didn't delete "new" images - as they could still be being used in a not-yet-saved editor. It also feels like a bit of a "sledgehammer" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the entity with the editing text a `post`. A `post` has a field of array type called `image_urls` (if your database does not support it, you can serialize this to array).

### New post

For a new post, `image_urls` list is empty. When the user uploads images during editing, the urls are stored in `image_urls` as a set. After user saves the post, a function checks the `img` tags in the post body, creating another url set called `final_image_urls`. The difference between `final_image_urls` set and the `image_urls` set is deleted.

### Existing posts

Editing an existing post, works just like a new post, except the starting `image_urls` field is not empty.

### Supporting revisions

When supporting post revisions, like SO does, this gets complicated.